# Suppose you have no static keyword in Java

Tags: java

Suppose you have no static keyword in Java but you still want the same functionality. How would you go about it?

Comment: but you DO have a static keyword in Java. Is this not the same as asking "imagine if you monitors had not been invented, how would you see your code?" Or am I missing your point?

Comment: I imagine most of the downvoters are thinking "Why would you ever want to do this", but we all had this problem when we were learning how to program, and we didn't know any other way.

Comment: Question is highly hypothetical.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that does not exist in the real world.

Comment: I almost tried to argue and then realized that if `main()` weren't static, the world would collapse.

Comment: In your hypothetical world, your application's entry point would be an instance method. That instance could be used as a repository of all global data.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik What created the instance method?

Comment: @john The programmer created the instance method. We are not *things* (not yet, at least :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a data structure that maps Class instances to values that are associated with that class instead of a particular instance of that class, but like other people are saying, this is probably too hypothetical to be of any value.